# Pick one row for each pair of parent-child and child-parent relationships

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm stuck with this problem and I could use some help.

I'm working with a table called **dependencies**.

A simple example

```
ID, parent, dependent, relationship
1234, John, Mike, Parent
1235, Mike, John, Child
1236, Nancy, John, Spouse
1237, John, Nancy, Spouse
1238, Peter, Mike, Sibling
1239, Mike, Peter, Sibling
```

Some of this dependencies are "mirror dependencies" (Like 1234 and 1235)

- John is **Parent** of Mike
- Mike is **Child** of John

The requirement is to retrieve one relationship by each pair of users, meaning
we need to include one record per each pair **(John, Mike)**, **(John, Nancy)** and **(Peter, Mike)** (its actually a `person_key` instead of name, so shouldn't be any duplication, but for the sake of the example I use the name)

```
1234, John, Mike, Parent
1237, John, Nancy, Spouse
1238, Peter, Mike, Sibling
```

or

```
1235, Mike, John, Child
1236, Nancy, John, Spouse
1239, Mike, Peter, Sibling
```

Any idea how to use SQL in order to skip the mirror records from the set?

Comment: Skipping result sets like this isn't so easy, you would need to split the table (a standard split function with a comma as the delimiter would do) first, then use the split to search for matches, then only choose the ones that were the first of the matches or didn't have a match (if this is even possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @Dependencies TABLE
([ID] int, [parent] varchar(50), [dependent] varchar(50), [relationship] varchar(50));

INSERT INTO @Dependencies
([ID], [parent], [dependent], [relationship])
VALUES
(1234, 'John', 'Mike', 'Parent'),
(1235, 'Mike', 'John', 'Child'),
(1236, 'Nancy', 'John', 'Spouse'),
(1237, 'John', 'Nancy', 'Spouse'),
(1238, 'Peter', 'Mike', 'Sibling'),
(1239, 'Mike', 'Peter', 'Sibling');
```

**Query**

Calculate `MIN` and `MAX` of `(parent, dependent)` and then you can group them together.

```
SELECT
    ID
    ,CASE WHEN [parent] < [dependent] THEN [parent] ELSE [dependent] END AS MinRelationship
    ,CASE WHEN [parent] > [dependent] THEN [parent] ELSE [dependent] END AS MaxRelationship
    ,[relationship]
FROM @Dependencies
;
```

**Result**

```
+------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+
|  ID  | MinRelationship | MaxRelationship | relationship |
+------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+
| 1234 | John            | Mike            | Parent       |
| 1235 | John            | Mike            | Child        |
| 1236 | John            | Nancy           | Spouse       |
| 1237 | John            | Nancy           | Spouse       |
| 1238 | Mike            | Peter           | Sibling      |
| 1239 | Mike            | Peter           | Sibling      |
+------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+
```

The rest depends on which row from each pair you want to choose. For example, we may want to choose a row with the smallest `ID`. `CTE_MinMax` is the simple query above. `CTE_rn` adds a number to each row partitioned by the pair and ordered by `ID`. The final `SELECT` returns only one row for each pair.

The query will work correctly if there is only one entry (not a pair), or if there are more than 2 entries.

```
WITH
CTE_MinMax
AS
(
    SELECT
        ID
        ,CASE WHEN [parent] < [dependent] THEN [parent] ELSE [dependent] END AS MinRelationship
        ,CASE WHEN [parent] > [dependent] THEN [parent] ELSE [dependent] END AS MaxRelationship
        ,[relationship]
    FROM @Dependencies
)
,CTE_rn
AS
(
    SELECT
        ID
        ,MinRelationship
        ,MaxRelationship
        ,relationship
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MinRelationship, MaxRelationship ORDER BY ID) AS rn
    FROM CTE_MinMax
)
SELECT
    ID
    ,MinRelationship
    ,MaxRelationship
    ,relationship
FROM CTE_rn
WHERE rn = 1
;
```

**Result**

```
+------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+
|  ID  | MinRelationship | MaxRelationship | relationship |
+------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+
| 1234 | John            | Mike            | Parent       |
| 1236 | John            | Nancy           | Spouse       |
| 1238 | Mike            | Peter           | Sibling      |
+------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea!!
The calculation of min and max via cases allow me to group by and retrieve exactly what i need
I Appreciate very much your answer

Answer (score 0):

I think what I would do is actually store only one record in the table for the relationship. So you wouldn't add the 1239, Mike, Peter, Sibling record because you already have a record in there for Mike and Peter. Then in the case of the Parent/Child relationship you could make the assumption that the parent is always in the "parent" column, and the "child" is in the dependent column.

So essentially all you would have in the table would be:

```
1234, John, Mike, Parent
1237, John, Nancy, Spouse
1238, Peter, Mike, Sibling
```

So if you were looking for the parents of Mike you would do something like:

```
select * from table where dependent = 'Mike' and relationship = 'Parent'
```

If you were looking for the spouse of John:

```
select * from table where (parent = 'John' or dependent = 'John') and relationship = 'Spouse'
```

If you were looking for Peter's Siblings:

```
select * from table where (parent = 'Peter' or dependent = 'Peter') and relationship = 'Sibling'
```

That's how I'd approach it anyway, it will make your queries much simpler than trying to  skip the "mirror records".

Comment: Hi Jacob, thank you for your help
I would love to store the data in other way, but we receive the data in that format. 

My goal is to retrieve only one record per pair, the table contain thousands of records, so is not as simple as create one query per pair. If i need to retrieve one single record your solution would work great, but my case is more general than one record in the table.
Thanks again